# How can I left-align elements together in the center of my page when they aren't next to each other in the DOM?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For the purposes of this question, my website consists of a header, footer, and a main column, which contains the article and its table of contents, side by side. The main column is centered, and due to the table of contents, *its width isn't fixed*. What I would like to do, is move the contents of the header and footer (which I've wrapped into `.main-column`), so that their left edge coincides with the centered main column.

I cannot simply put the header and footer inside of `<main>`, which already gets centered, as *I would like to have a border (think `<hr>`) that spans the entire width of the viewport*.

One workaround that comes to mind is to set the `margin-left` of the header and footer with JavaScript. However, I would rather avoid relying on JavaScript for page layout, reserving it for small, progressive enhancements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

footer {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.main-column {
  /* imagine this makes things aligned */
  margin-left: 5rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

article {
  max-width: 20rem;
}

nav {
  background: gray;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="main-column">
      <h1>Header here</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <article>
      <h1>This is some article</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
        hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
        augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
        vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
    </article>
    <nav>
      <h3>Table of contents</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Some</li>
        <li>links</li>
        <li>here</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </main>
  
  <footer>
    <div class="main-column">
      <h1>Footer here</h1>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is the main column's width not fixed "due to the table of contents"? What does the table of contents have to do with the width of the article column's width?

Comment: So tldr; you just want the `header` and `footer` to share the dynamic width of `main` for one uniform center column of content?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @TylerH `article` has a `max-width`, and before it gets reduced, a media query (not shown here) will hide the ToC. Thus, `article` effectively has a fixed width, and if not for the ToC, `main` would too. However, I am now realizing that this is irrelevant detail, and I could make the example more minimal by including only one element in `main` that doesn't have any set width.

Comment: I think you'll need to modify your markup for this (or use JS). If you want to avoid JS, that's fine, we can leave the tags as they are now, but if you are open to or prefer a JS solution to modifying your markup, then you should add the JS tag to the question.

Comment: @TylerH I am entirely open to modifying the markup itself. Though I don't see how to arrange it so that these can be centered together while allowing a full-width border in between

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding you're just wanting something like below. Width of main is still dynamic but do need to take advantage of some box model forming.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  border: rgba(255,0,0,.2) 2px dashed;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

hr {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
  margin: 0 -100%;
}

/*
header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

footer {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
*/

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

article {
  max-width: 25rem;
}

nav {
  background: gray;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">

    <header>
      <div class="main-column">
        <h1>Header here</h1>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </header>

    <main>
      <article>
        <h1>This is some article</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
          hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
          augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
          vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
          hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
          augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
          vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
          hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
          augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
          vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
      </article>
      <nav>
        <h3>Table of contents</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Some</li>
          <li>links</li>
          <li>here</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <hr>
      <div class="main-column">
        <h1>Footer here</h1>
      </div>
    </footer>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

However if you're maybe less familiar with DOM structuring I'm going to go ahead and suggest the easier route like shown below using javascript. Primarily because to effectively use html / css purely in a cross-browser and responsive capacity can be tough without more experience. So something like this gets you closer to your goal post with less explanation. Side note, consideration was not given to active window resizing to recalc (since you have a max-width set on your main content which would wrap) so you'd need to add a listener for that event and could use the same method to re-calc the layout portions, but that could be a separate question or an opportunity to learn. Cheers

```js
// Wait for the DOM nodes to merely be present with DOMContentLoaded event.
// Keep in mind the general load event vs DOMContentLoaded if need to eval a full loaded page. 
// Could come in handy when slow loading images and such impact redraws.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
  
  // Get the DOM nodes we wish to interact with.
  const getEl = function(tag) { return document.getElementById(tag) },
        header = getEl('header'),
        main = getEl('main'),
        footer = getEl('footer');
  
  try {
    // If everything is found, let's make the header and footer have a uniform width with <main>
    header.style.width = footer.style.width = `${main.clientWidth}px`;
  } catch {
    // If something goes wrong, let's catch a useful error to learn from and troubleshoot.
    // Like if a DOM node we looked for above isn't present.
    console.error('Houston we have a problem, with your html elements.');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* Use flex for a quick layout parent structure */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

header, main, footer {
    /* set the elements to center horizontally */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  /* comment out align-items if you want table of contents full height */
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: rgba(255,0,0,.25) 3px dashed;
}

article {
  max-width: 25rem;
}

nav {
  background: gray;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1>Header here</h1>
</header>
<hr>
<main id="main">
  <article>
    <h1>This is some article</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
      hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
      augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
      vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
      hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
      augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
      vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
      hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
      augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
      vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
  </article>
  <nav>
    <h3>Table of contents</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Some</li>
      <li>links</li>
      <li>here</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
<hr>
<footer id="footer">
  <h1>Footer here</h1>
</footer>
```

Comment: I edited my question to make it look closer to what I have in mind (by adding a hardcoded 10rem margin on `.main-content`). Note that, while the header content is left-aligned within the column, the border spans the entire viewport.

Comment: That's closer to what I had in mind. Though, is there a way to avoid the `hr` overflowing to the right, so that there is no unnecessary horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Sure you can just adjust wrapper, see update.

Comment: Ah, but then if something actually overflows, there won't be a way to scroll and see it.

Comment: @NieDzejkob generally if something overflows horizontally there's other issues in your designing. Either way no worries, I'm going to go ahead and delete this, spent too much free time already. Cheers :)

Comment: @NieDzejkob see updated update of updated answer and will hope this can be put to bed because that's where I'm heading. Sorry I was busy and not quicker to accommodate. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I am aware of is to change the DOM such that everything can be centered as one `div`, together. To achieve the borders in this configuration, we can use a negative margin to make them poke out.

Unfortunately, this requires adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the *entire page*, which might be undesirable due to other content.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

article {
  max-width: 15rem;
}

nav {
  background: gray;
}

ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

header hr, footer hr {
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 calc(50% - 50vw);
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Header here</h1>
    <hr>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <article>
      <h1>This is some article</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mattis leo ut metus egestas porttitor eu ac risus. Fusce convallis posuere diam ut dapibus. Mauris at velit ex. Ut malesuada sollicitudin magna, ac imperdiet ipsum elementum in. In
        hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam egestas ligula sed erat vestibulum porta. Suspendisse potenti. Donec facilisis risus placerat tincidunt lacinia. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam in pharetra lectus. Suspendisse sodales, erat iaculis auctor lacinia,
        augue dolor lobortis dui, quis fermentum neque nulla ac lacus. Morbi id nulla iaculis, laoreet dui eget, vehicula nulla. Donec eget purus sit amet nibh mollis tempor. Proin hendrerit nisi quis orci placerat ullamcorper. Integer congue mauris dui,
        vel tempor libero ultrices non. Aliquam in nisl magna.</p>
    </article>
    <nav>
      <h3>Table of contents</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Some</li>
        <li>links</li>
        <li>here</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </main>
  
  <footer>
    <hr>
    <h1>Footer here</h1>
  </footer>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```